# SSL Certificate .csr .key .cert files

Tags: ssl, server, certificate, ssl-certificate

How can I add an ssl self signed certificate to the server?

I have cert, csr and .key files.

Comment: Hi! Is your server a web server? In this case, wich framework you are using? (nginx, apache, etc)

Comment: I have to do a favor. I have access to the server but I don't know what are they using. how can I check it? sorry, this is the first time that I'm making this, I have no idea and google search helps only for local apache server. I have access via cPanel (and FTP) for the public_html folder

Comment: I found on the server an ssl folder with 3 subfolders for the 3 kind of files, certs, keys, csrs. should I just copy the files there?

Comment: The certificate installation depends on witch server framework you are using. In apache servers or nginx for example, the first step is copy yours cert files to specific folders, but the process is a little more large. First we need to know witch framework the web server is using. Take a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/120783/can-i-detect-what-webserver-a-website-is-using) to do that. In shorts execute this command pointing your addresses 'wget --save-headers google.com'

Comment: Webserver 
Apache/2.2.3 CentOS

Sender Policy Framework
Qualifier  Mechanism  Argument
+ (Pass)  ip4  
+ (Pass)  a  
+ (Pass)  mx  
+ (Pass)  ip4 
~ (SoftFail)  all

Comment: Hi @millrock I will write the solution in the answer section. I hope you'll manage to do that. Please mark as answered.

Comment: If you have a CSR why not get it signed, instead of using a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate installation depends on which server framework you are using. In apache servers or nginx for example, the first step is copy yours cert files to specific folders, but the process is a little more large. First, we need to know which framework this web server is using. Take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/120783/can-i-detect-what-webserver-a-website-is-using) to do that. In shorts execute this command pointing your addresses

```
wget --save-headers google.com
```

**Update:**

Now we know, that your server is apache CentOS, you just follow [this oficial](https://wiki.centos.org/es/HowTos/Https) guide.

Comment: thanks for the answer!

I have FTP connection via Filezilla and I'm using a windows computer.
So I have to create the /etc/pki/tls/certs and /etc/pki/tls/private folders and copy them there. 
How can I use a commander? vi +/SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf 
is "vi" for Mac, isn't it?

Comment: @Millrock I recommend you that you open a new thread for this topic. Anyway, in my opinion the better way to manage a linux based remote server (centos it is) is connecting via ssh to the remote console. In windows you can use putty to do that. Please don't forguet mark you question as answered for my answer.